# How to run React application on prdouction with http server

Tags: reactjs, express

I am developing a react application and now I plan to go live on production. I am refering [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) guide on how to deploy the react application. It says if the react app has client side routing, we should handle it in the http server(expressjs in my case) itself, like below:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

So whenever there is a path change on the browser, the http server renders the entire bundle again. But if that is the case, isn't it defeating the entire purpose of using react for developing single page application, where there are minimal page refresh?

I don't know if my thinking is right or not. Is there any more optimal way to run React app on production with `expressjs`?

Thank You!

Comment: Have you verified this: "whenever there is a path change on the browser, the http server renders the entire bundle again"

Comment: Yeah I can see the page is getting refreshed and several requests are happening in the console

Comment: It will reload the page only when the route is changed manually from browser, it happens with all the SPA. If routes are changed in app then it won't reload the page.

Comment: The app will only be fully loaded ONCE. And once the JS is loaded, with a route setup like react router, it will take over the client side navigation so the page won't be fully loaded again.

Comment: Serve static files with nginx. It will be much faster

Answer (score 1):

The app will not reload when it changes its own routes, but if you manually change the route in the browser it *will* reload.

---

When visiting yourapp.com:

1. GET request to server
2. server responds with app
3. app runs in the browser

There is only a single initial request to the server. Of course there's a new request when manually changing the url.

---

**Why the asterisk/wildcard/glob/*?**

The wildcard allows for the user to visit a non-root path, still be served your app, and then allow your client side routing to do the logic based on the entered path.

---

**Should you use Express.js to serve your React app?**

While you *can* spin up a server just to serve your static react app build, you should consider serving your static bundle directly using one of the other options later in the doc (e.g. Netlify, S3/Cloudfront).